# To be left to + present participle

Tags: present-participles

Is this a correct way to write? I mean using present participle extemporizing.

1. Too important to be left to
   'extemporizing'

Comment: That's just fine.

Comment: Why not 'to +  extempore' ?

Comment: Okay so extemporizing is working as a noun/ gerund. I think the whole sentence makes sense. Something is too important to be left to extemporizing (putting in some kind of category in this case 'extemporizing') like too important to be left to seclusion.

Comment: In response to "to extempore" - "extempore" is not a verb https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extempore

Comment: Yeah 'extempore' is an adjective but 'extemporizing' is a noun/ gerund.

Comment: Yes, which is why your sentence as asked is OK.

Comment: Are you sure you understand what "extemporising" means? Saying something is *too important to be left to seclusion* makes absolutely no sense to me, and *too important to be left to 'extemporizing'* doesn't look like a natural way to say what I *assume* is the intended meaning *(You should work out what you're going to say in advance; don't just improvise).*

Comment: "Too important to be left to seclusion" according to me means that something is important enough and not to be ignored or put in a cold bag. 'Extemporizing' means not prepared. "Too important to be left to extemporizing" means something is important and can't be seen as an extempore speech or something. This is what I think.

Comment: Now does that make sense?